# Correctly parse arguments in script behaving like a shell called through SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, command, arguments

I have a server with a very limited used whom I want to be able to run two very specific (and custom) instructions through SSH. In order to do that, I have set the shell for that limited user to be a custom BASH script that will only accept those two *"commands"*.

This is the `/etc/passwd` for that user:

```
limited:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/limited:/usr/sbin/limited_shell.bash
```

This is the `limited_shell.bash` script (well, what I have so far, which is not working properly):

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly RECORDER_SCRIPT="/usr/sbin/record.py"
echo "Verifying params: \$1: $1, \$2: $2"
shift

case $1 in
  [0-9]*)
    nc -z localhost $1 < /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
    result=$?
    if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]
    then
      echo "O"
    else
      echo "C"
    fi
    exit $result
    ;;
  record)
    $RECORDER_SCRIPT ${*:3}
    exit $?
    ;;
  *)
    exit 0
    ;;
  esac
exit 0
```

As you might deduce from the script, the two commands I want `limited_shell.bash` to accept are: a number and a "record" string. When `limited_shell.bash` is called with a number, it will return whether it corresponds with an opened or closed local port. The other allowed command triggers a call to a python script (`/usr/sbin/record.py`) which then records some video from an input. This second command needs to be called with extra arguments, and that's where the problems start.

When, in another machine I try to remotely execute the `record` command...

```
ssh limited@192.168.1.5 record -option1 foo -option2 bar
```

... what actually arrives to `limited_shell.bash` is: `-c 'record -option1 foo -option2 bar'` (technically two arguments, one of them being `-c` and the second one being the whole string *command+args* that I want to execute)

I thought about shifting the first argument (the `-c`), and split the second argument (the actual `record` command with arguments) by space, but that is dirty and will give me a lot of troubles if one of the parameters I want to pass to the `record.py` script is an string containing an space.

What is the right way of parsing the commands? I'm sure there has to be a better way than shifting and splitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *script* is meant to implement a *shell*. That is, a command line interpreter.

When you run:

```
ssh host echo '$foo;' rm -rf '/*'
```

`ssh` (the client), concatenates the arguments (with ASCII SPC characters), and sends that to `sshd`. `sshd` calls the user's login shell as:

```
exec("the-shell", "-c", "the command-line")
```

That is here:

```
exec("the-shell", "-c", "echo $foo; rm -rf /*")
```

And that would have been exactly the same had you run:

```
ssh host echo '$foo;' 'rm -rf' '/*'
ssh host 'echo $foo;' "rm -rf /*"
ssh host 'echo $foo; rm -rf /*'
```

(the later one being the preferable one as it makes it clearer what is being done).

It's up to `the-shell` to decide what to do with that command line. For instance, a Bourne-like shell would expand `$foo` to the content of the `foo` variable, it would consider `;` as a command separator, and would expand `/*` into a sorted list of non-hidden files in `/`.

Now, in your case since, you can do whatever you want. But since that's meant to be a *restricted* user, you may want to do as little as possible, for instance, not expand variable, command substitution, globs, not allow several commands, not do redirections...

Another thing to bear in mind in that `bash` reads `~/.bashrc` when called over `ssh` even when non-interactive (as in when interpreting scripts). So you probably want to avoid `bash` (or at least call it as `sh`) or make sure `~/.bashrc` is not writabe by the user or use the `--norc` option.

Now, since it's up to you do define how the command line is interpreted, you can either simply split one space, newline or tab:

```
#!/bin/sh -
[ "$1" = "-c" ] || exit
set -f
set -- $2
case $1 in
    (record) 
        shift
        exec /usr/sbin/record.py "$@"
        ;;
    ("" | *[!0-9]*)
        echo >&2 "command not supported"
        exit 1
        ;;
    (*)
        nc ...
        ;;
esac
```

But that means `record` won't be able to take arguments that contain spaces, tabs or newlines or that are empty.

If you want them to be able to do that, you need to provide with some sort of quoting syntax.

`zsh` has a quote parsing tool that can help you there:

```
#! /bin/zsh -f
[ "$1" = "-c" ] || exit
set -- "${(Q@)${(Z:cn:)2}}"
case $1 in
    (record) 
        shift
        exec /usr/sbin/record.py "$@"
        ;;
    ("" | *[!0-9]*)
        echo >&2 "command not supported"
        exit 1
        ;;
    (*)
        nc ...
        ;;
esac
```

That supports single, double quotes and backslashes. But it would also consider things like `$(foo bar)` as a single argument (even if not expanding it).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

# domain-specific language: provide a "record" command
record () {
    /usr/sbin/record.py "$@"
}

command=$2
set -- $command   # re-use the positional parameters
case $1 in
    record) 
        # let the shell parse the given command
        eval "$command"
        ;;
    +([0-9]))    
        nc ... # as above
        ;;
    *) exit 0 ;;
esac
```

Note I use the extended glob pattern `+([0-9])` to match a word that is one or more digits. The pattern `[0-9]*` matches a word *beginning* with a digit, so `1foo` would match -- I assume that's not what you want.

**Caution** the use of `eval` is highly dangerous. Consider adding additional command verification to the command the user is giving you. What happens when:

```
ssh limited@192.168.1.5 record -option1 foo -option2 \`rm -rf /\`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest a simpler approach that requires a little more setup but saves writing a complex, error-prone script.

You can declare that an SSH public key is [only allowed to run a specific command](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT). Generate the key pair, copy the public key to the server, and add a `command=…` directive to it. Do this for each of the small number of commands you want to allow. This means you lines like this in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server:

```
command="/path/to/command1" ssh-rsa AAAA…== key1
command="/path/to/command2" no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA…== key2
```

When you execute the remote command, choose the appropriate private key:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key1.id_rsa server.example.com 'this is ignored'
```

You can write any shell code in the `command` directive. The command supplied by the client is available in the variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56412446/151312

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413511/151312